# App crashes due to TextInputlayout declaration

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio

I am new to android i am developing and application where the app crashes when i click the fab button to open new activity.Button is working fine but due to first 3 lines of code app is crashing as i want to validated the form i used setError for TextInputLayout but the due to declaration of TextInputLayout the app crashes...

```
 final   TextInputLayout name12=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.NameWrapper);
    final   TextInputLayout payment12=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.PaymentWrapper);
    final   TextInputLayout leave12=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.LeaveWrapper);


    final EditText Name1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText PhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final EditText JobDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    final EditText Payment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    final EditText Leave = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    final EditText Adharno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    final TextView Start = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final TextView End = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final RadioButton Daily = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Rb1);
    final RadioButton Monthly = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Rb2);
    final Button AddEmp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    final Button Cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
   final RadioGroup myRadiogeoup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(Rbg);



    //Add Employee Btn
    AddEmp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String name1=Name1.getText().toString();
            String phone1=PhoneNo.getText().toString();
            String jobdesc=JobDesc.getText().toString();
            String payment=Payment.getText().toString();
            String leave=Leave.getText().toString();
            String ahdarno=Adharno.getText().toString();

            int id=myRadiogeoup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
           final RadioButton mySelectedRadioButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(id);
            String paymethod=mySelectedRadioButton.getText().toString();
            String startd=Start.getText().toString();
            String end=End.getText().toString();


     //validation and data insertion

           if (name12.getEditText().length() == 0) {
                name12.setError("Enter Name");
                name12.setErrorEnabled(true);

            }
            else{
                name12.setErrorEnabled(false);
            }



              if (leave12.getEditText().length() == 0) {

                leave12.setError("Enter date");
                leave12.setErrorEnabled(true);
            }
            else
            {
                leave12.setErrorEnabled(false);
            }

            if (payment12.getEditText().length() == 0) {

                payment12.setError("Enter Password");
                payment12.setErrorEnabled(true);
            }
            else{
                payment12.setErrorEnabled(false);

            }

           if(Start.getText().length()==0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter Start Date",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data Entered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        }
    });
```

please help if anyone knows any other way of validation.
sorry for my wrong code or if the method is wrong cuz i am new to android

--logcat

```
 24 12:11:06.725 20230-20230/com.navinkadlak.typroject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.navinkadlak.typroject, PID: 20230
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.navinkadlak.typroject/com.navinkadlak.typroject.addemployee}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2555)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2629)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5706)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1033)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                                                           at com.navinkadlak.typroject.addemployee.onCreate(addemployee.java:33)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2502)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2629) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5706) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1033) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
```

Comment: Can you please post your crash log?

Answer (score 2):

```
final   TextInputLayout name12=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.NameWrapper);
final   TextInputLayout payment12=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.PaymentWrapper);
final   TextInputLayout leave12=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.LeaveWrapper);
```

Compare R.id.NameWrapper,R.id.PaymentWrapper, R.id.LeaveWrapper with xlm. One of them refer to linearlayout so its not cast into textinputlayout.

Answer (score 0):

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` tells you exactly what happened.

You are trying to cast some `View` to `TextInputLayout` but it is actually the `LinearLayout`.

So one of:

1. `R.id.NameWrapper`
2. `R.id.PaymentWrapper`
3. `R.id.LeaveWrapper;`

Is Linear Layout actually.

Comment: Yeah i too figure out that after going through the logcat ,anyways thanks for commenting !!